# Symmetric PDF proof

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing

If F(x<sub>u</sub>) = u, then show that if f(-x) = f(x), then x<sub>1-u</sub>=-x<sub>u</sub> where:

F is CDF

f is PDF.

In my mind, I understand why this is the case, but I'm having trouble writing a proof to show it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx=u$, and define $I:=\int_{-\infty}^{-a}f(x)dx$. By $x\mapsto -x$, $I=\int_a^\infty f(-x)dx$. Since $f$ is symmetric (or *even*, if you prefer that term),$$I=\int_a^\infty f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx=1-u.$$

Comment: It seems as though in this proof that you're under the assumption that $\int_{-\infty}^{-a}f(x)dx=1-u$ at the start. How do you actually get to this point though? I understand the step where you replace x with -x, but it seems as though you're just replacing -u with $\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx$ in the last step because of the assumption you made in your first statement which you didn't prove.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out on my own. The proof you wrote was just out of order. It makes more sense to me, and it might make more sense to others in this order. 

1. $\int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx=u$
2. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=1$
3. $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx = 1-u$
4.  $\int_{-\infty}^{-a} f(-x)dx=1-u$.

Comment: @SD'Anc I've rearranged it a little.